# Is there anywhere one may obtain recommended readings from textbooks, similar to a university course?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, learning

I'm currently going through Spivak's Calculus as a form of supplementary material since I find the 'notes' provided by my introductory calculus course lecturer is too hand-wavy and not very intuitive. I was wondering if any of you guys are familiar with whether there is anywhere suggesting specific readings from such books(not limited to Spivak, since I am interested in other textbooks discussing topics on Real Analysis like Rudin's, and Linear Algebra like Axler/Friedman).

This would be beneficial as I may not have the time to read it end-to-end and digest it at an appropriate pace, and most importantly would like some insight into which exercises would be most critical for efficient and effective learning.

Comment: Not everyone who does mathematics is a man. Consider using gender neutral language such as "they" and "person" instead of "he" and "sir" when talking about other users.

Comment: At the end of Spivak's book, there's a suggested reading section. Have you checked it out?

Comment: I have, actually. I was thinking more along the lines of specific chapters in certain books which are widely read, which may be more relevant/important to the study of specific topics like analysis/linear algebra.